# Externalizing tikz diagrams with arguments

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

Since my Latex document involves many tikz pictures, often similar, I defined a command with arguments which does a tikz drawing with "decorations" controlled by these arguments:

```
\diag{<-}{white}{black}{$n$}{$i$}{$j$}
```

produces [image]. That allows for a quick change of decorations in the latex file and any edits can be done in the single tikz code. However, there are lots of pictures, like these and others, in my document and it takes a long time to latex. Is there a way to externalize all these pictures without sacrificing the convenience of the current setup?

The code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{expl3,tikz,ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, math, decorations.markings, arrows.meta,calc,shapes.misc}
\usepgfmodule{decorations}
\tikzset{->-/.style n args={2}{decoration={markings, mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{#2}}}, postaction={decorate}}} %adding end=stealth will make the arrows thicker.  
\ExplSyntaxOn
 \cs_new_eq:NN \ifstreqF \str_if_eq:nnF
 \cs_new_eq:NN \ifstreqTF \str_if_eq:nnTF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\tikzset{-o-/.code 2 args={\ifstreqF{#2}{} %none}{\ifstreqTF{#2}{>}
  {\pgfkeysalso{decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{#2}}}
                ,postaction={decorate}}
}
{\ifstreqTF{#2}{<}
   {\pgfkeysalso{decoration={markings,mark=at position #1 with {\arrow{#2}}}
                ,postaction={decorate}}
    }
   {\pgfkeysalso{decoration={markings,
                mark=at position #1 with 
                {\draw[black, fill={#2}] circle[radius=2pt];}}
                ,postaction={decorate}}
    }
 }
 }}} 

 \newcommand{\diag}[6]{
  %#1 arrow direction, #2,3 white, black, > or <, #4: label the central edge, #5,6 labels
 \raisebox{-0.4\height}{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzmath{\xwidth=1.7;}
    \fill[gray!20!white] (0,0)rectangle(\xwidth,1);
    \tikzmath{\xw=\xwidth;}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{<-}}{\tikzmath{\yw=0.2;}}{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{->}}{\tikzmath{\yw=0;}}{\tikzmath{\yw=0.1;}}}
    \draw[very thick, #1] (\xw,0) --(\xw,1); %wall
    \tikzmath{\ya=\yw+0.6; \yb=\yw+0.2; \ycent=\ya/2+\yb/2;} 
    \coordinate[label={right:{\small #5}}] (A) at (\xw,\ya); 
    \coordinate[label={right:{\small #6}}] (B) at (\xw,\yb);
    \draw[thick, -o-={0.6}{#2}] (1.2,\ycent)-- (A);
    \draw[thick, -o-={0.6}{#3}] (1.2,\ycent)-- (B);
    \draw[thick] (0.5,\ycent) -- (1.2,\ycent);
    \coordinate[label={above:{\small #4}}] (B) at (0.85,\yb+0.2);
    \draw[thick, -o-={0.4}{#2}] (0,\ya) -- (0.5,\ycent);
    \draw[thick, -o-={0.4}{#3}] (0,\yb) -- (0.5,\ycent);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }} 

\begin{document}
My diagram: \diag{<-}{white}{black}{$n$}{$i$}{$j$}
\end{document}
```